# custom alerts appear at the same time One behind the other

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

In my jQuery Mobile App i have used Notification plugin in order to use custom Alert , and the problem is that all alerts appear at the same time One behind the other ,how can i prevent that? what should i do to solve this problem?

please help me ....

this is my code

```
 if( $.trim($('#Name').attr('value') ).length== 0  )
    {    
      navigator.notification.alert(' Insert your Name',alertDismissed,'Missed Value',  'OK');


    }
   if( $.trim($('#PhoneNum').attr('value') ).length== 0  )
    {    
      navigator.notification.alert(' Insert your Phone Number',alertDismissed,'Missed Value',  'OK');

    }
   if( $.trim($('#Address').attr('value') ).length== 0  )
    {    
      navigator.notification.alert(' Insert your Address',alertDismissed,'Missed Value',  'OK');


    }


   function  alertDismissed()
  {



   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect all of your alertmessages in an array and iterate over it, starting the next call on the close event of the previous alertwindow.